# Can't connect to GTA V Online on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online

I have Xbox Live Gold but when I try to connect online (in game top right) it says "your connection to Xbox Live has been lost please sign in again."
I sign in and it goes in circles sending me to sign in again.
I can sign into Xbox Live from console, but not in the game. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Check your internet connection speed and strength. If it is low, there may be problems.

Sometimes the xbox server closes down for repairs, this may be the problem. If it is, it shouldn't last too long.

The same thing may happen to the GTA server. If this is the issue. It shouldn't take too long either.

Maybe there is something wrong with your xbox gold membership, it may have expired. But this shouldn't happen. Unless you are on the free trial for gold.

The same thing happened to my friend on a different game, it kept crashing their xbox. But a new update was released for the game, and this stopped.

If none of these answers are the case, contact Rockstart Games or Xbox and see if they have an answer.

Comment: https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200426246-GTA-Online-Server-Status-Latest-Updates at least the server status says is up